# MYSQL CURDATE() -7 omits days in December when asked at the first of January

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table that holds holds data for past and upcoming classes. My query asks to output any class from 7 days ago forward. ie. If today is Friday, I would be able to see last weeks classes and the upcoming classes.

It has always performed as expected until the New Year. It is January 2nd and I can only see classes for this year. Even though there was a class on December 30th.

```
SELECT * FROM DriverEducationClass WHERE classDate > CURDATE() -7 ORDER BY classDate;
```

It has worked in previous month to month changes. Does this have something to do with a year change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the change-of-year, and everything to do with your subtraction:

```
mysql> select curdate() - 7, curdate() - interval 7 day;
+---------------+----------------------------+
| curdate() - 7 | curdate() - interval 7 day |
+---------------+----------------------------+
|      20150095 | 2014-12-26                 |
+---------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note how your `-7` version returns a wonky integer, while the `- interval` version returns a proper date.

Comment: The integer is not entirely wonky, it's just `20150102 - 7`.

Comment: true, but it also becomes useless for comparisons against other date/datetime fields. month 0 and day 95?

Comment: Thank you. I know have a better understanding.